# CRASHES & ANRS report

Tags: android

I am new with android and I just put out my first app.I got the following error and I having difficulty understanding where in the code something went wrong at which line in the code it crashed (I am used to the Log.d(,"")) Thanks in advance for any help or explanation.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow
at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getShadowBackground(CardViewEclairMr1.java:159)
at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getMinWidth(CardViewEclairMr1.java:150)
at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:181)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17327)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:6874)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1396)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onLayout(NestedScrollView.java:1617)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2348)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2061)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6529)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:812)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:612)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:798)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit:

I am adding the xml that I suspect:
I think when this gets called it crashes I am not sure whats wrong

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:transitionName="square"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">



        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/info_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
            cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            cardElevation="20dp">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/favorite_title"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:text="@string/favorites_content" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_pick_county_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="475dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:transitionName="square2"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things :

One :

Change `myHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.SOME_COLOR);` to `((CardView)myHolder.itemView).setCardBackgroundColor(Color.SOME_COLOR);` wherever you are using

Two :

I assume you tested your application well before uploading it into Play Store. That means the error has something to do with the release apk. Normally when we build a signed apk, [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) will try to minify the code including external libraries. That cause crashes sometimes.

So, what you can do is exclude all external libraries from the ProGuard minification process. Find the file called `proguard-android.txt` for your module. And add the following to it,

```
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep interface org.** { *; }
-keep enum org.** { *; }
```

This will exclude all classes/interfaces/enums whose package name starts with `org`. Do the same for all external libraries. Build signed release apk again. Make sure you test the app using the signed apk, not the debug one.

EDIT :

Add this to your pro-guard file,

```
-keep class com.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.android.** { *; }
-keep enum com.android.** { *; }

-keep class com.github.** { *; }
-keep interface com.github.** { *; }
-keep enum com.github.** { *; }

-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep enum com.squareup.** { *; }

-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keep interface com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keep enum com.fasterxml.** { *; }

-keep class de.hdodenhof.** { *; }
-keep interface de.hdodenhof.** { *; }
-keep enum de.hdodenhof.** { *; }
```

Comment: on my nexus it still works perfect its on other people phone that it is crashing

Comment: Which is your android version?

Comment: Also, can you post java code where you use cardview?

Comment: its a lot of code i put it here http://pastebin.com/8DvAv3Nk and here http://pastebin.com/2bi9Qxs6 thank you for trying to help me

Comment: In [http://pastebin.com/2bi9Qxs6](http://pastebin.com/2bi9Qxs6), line numbers 86 and 88

Comment: Thank you @Msp ! I still need some help with step two http://pastebin.com/q8qYusd1

Comment: Post dependencies section of your build.gradle. I can help

Comment: Added proguard section

Comment: I am pushing it up and if it stops crashing I will mark you as correct Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your logs. There is a crash that occured for one of your users, and which was reported through the Play Developper Console.

At some point of your code, your are trying to cast a `ColorDrawable` object into a `RoundRectDrawableWithShadow`, causing the crash.

The following lines are giving you the place where this is happening:

> at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getMinWidth(CardViewEclairMr1.java:150)

If it doesn't belong to your own classes, you might check if you are not doing a bad use of the support library, as it seems that the crash come from the use of the `android.support.v7.widget` package.

This kind of errors can also occure when you are shrinking, obfuscating or optimizing with proguard.

Comment: What do you suggest I do? the support library are written by the google people if I don`t use them there is no chance that my app will work for any older phone?

Comment: You can start by showing us the code where this is happening. This is just a crash report, I told you that it was giving you informations about a bug occuring on the specified line. Give us the code if you want more help, without we cannot do much for you

Comment: Give me a minute I will put in a pieces that i suspect

Comment: Its too big it dosen`t allow

Comment: Which part do you suspect?

Comment: i think this  myHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

Comment: Should I put out more classes to look over?